# Exchange Online Mail Queue

Tags: office365, exchange-server

Is it possible to call a web service when an email is sent by any user on O365 tenancy and the email message hits the outgoing queue? I would like to call a process when the email reaches queue and then the process will pick that message and do some processing and put it back in the queue. During this the email should never be sent unless the process has done its thing.

Is this possible? I have found the APIs but I am confused if its possible to do exactly what I am after. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think that such a way would exists and if it would I never would implement something like that.

**Reason:**
If a user is using S/Mime you might break the signature if you tamper the email in the queue. This is happening because the user is signing the content with his local S/Mime certificate which isn´t used by the server.

**Conclusion:** So whatever you wish to perform I would do that locally...